# Laravel whereHas count on Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel

In my current project, a `User` may join many `Organisations` and vice versa - An example of a many to many relationship. I'm trying to count the number of users who are currently unverified (where the `Verified` column on the user table is equal to 0).

My `User` model:

```
/**
 * Get the organisations that the user is a part of.
 */
public function organisation()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Organisation::class, 'organisation_users', 'user_id', 'organisation_id'
    )->withPivot(['role'])->orderBy('name', 'asc');
}
```

My `Organisation` model:

```
/**
 * Get all of the users that belong to the organisation.
 */
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        User::class, 'organisation_users', 'organisation_id', 'user_id'
    )->withPivot('role');
}
```

So if I want to count the number of unverified users I have the following method on the `Organisation` model:

```
/**
 * An organisation may have unverified users attached.
 */
public function unverifiedUsers()
{
    return $this->whereHas('users', function($query) {
        $query->where('verified', 0);
    })->get();
}
```

However, running `dd(\App\Organisation::find($org->id)->unverifiedUsers()->count());` only shows `1` when in fact there should be `10`. Am I structuring my relationships incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whereHas()` will return `0` or `1`. It just tells you if such a user exists.

The sollution is much simpler:

```php
public function unverifiedUsers()
{
    return $this->users()->where('verified', 0)->get();
}
```

If you only need the count:

```php
public function unverifiedUsersCount()
{
    return $this->users()->where('verified', 0)->count();
}
```